# Finding lat long in ArcGIS similar to as in Google Earth

Tags: arcgis-desktop, google-maps, google-earth, search, find

I want to know if there is some possibility to find lat long position in ArcGIS 10.0 as we can find on Google Earth. I have an assignment and doing this can save me a lot of time. I have already used the "Find" option in ArcGIS 10.0 which is limited to what I want.

[image]

In the question above use of "Google Earth" have been taken as an example only. I would like to find the lat long position in the platform of ArcGIS as I have been trying to find with "Find" tool, which did not help.

Comment: How precisely are you doing this in Google Earth?  Knowing that will make it much easier for potential answerers to suggest the ArcGIS for Desktop equivalent function.

Comment: As we enter some values in Google Earth e.g. 70.2356 34.5485 n it gives the result. Same or similar would work. Variation, I suppose, should depend on decimals after the point.

Comment: Please edit the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you are after the [GoTo XY](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-arcmap/using-the-go-to-xy-tool.htm) tool which is on the Tools toolbar:

> You can use this tool to type in x,y coordinates and navigate to them.
>   The coordinates you enter can be
>
> - Longitude-Latitude
> - ...

Comment: this might work, but my Arc crashes as soon as I initiate this, I'm using version 10.

Comment: Please **edit the question** to specify the version of ArcGIS in use.  "10"  is a series of release families, starting with 10.0 and its service packs (which have been retired), ranging to the current "10.4.1" and the imminent "10.5.0".

Answer (score 2):

Another option, if you have many lng/lat coordinates to display you may use this method:

1. Open up blank ArcMap and right click on Layers (data frame)>Properties>Coordinate System tab and search/select the WGS 1984 geographic coordinate system.
2. Put all your lng/lat coordintes in two different columns in a spreadsheet or comma delimited text file and then use the [Make XY Event Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-xy-event-layer.htm) tool to plot the many locations.